# Combining rotations and translations - Java 2D

Tags: java, java-2d

```
public void drawEarth(Graphics2D g2){
    theta -=0.1;

    g2.rotate(theta);
    g2.translate(50, 50);

    g2.setPaint(Color.blue);
    g2.fill(shape);
}

public void rotate(Graphics2D g2)
{
    theta -=0.1;

    g2.translate(50, 50);
    g2.rotate(theta);
}
```

I've written these two methods.  The first one causes the shape to revolve around a point, and I'm now trying to make the shape spin about its axis.  I've been told that doing translation before rotation would allow the shape to spin about it's axis (as shown in the second method), but I'm not sure how to combine these two translations so that it revolves and rotates?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) rather than code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

There is too many smart words to me but maybe you want do this:

```
g2.rotate(double theta, double x, double y)
```

[rotate in documentation:](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#rotate%28double,%20double,%20double%29)

> Concatenates the current Graphics2D
>   Transform with a translated rotation
>   transform.

Answer (score 0):

For an object it works like this: *An object always rotates around the Origin*.
And it also works like this `Scale --> Rotate --> Translate`.

If you want to rotate an object around its own axis, it has to be on the origin (which it is when you don't translate). Just call a rotate first and then translate it into the world. Once you have done that, you have to rotate it around your earth. So call a rotate again.

So you get this: `(Scale) --> Rotate on own axis --> Translate on own offset --> Translate to the earth --> Rotate around the earth`

I hope this helps. I don't know about the java API for this, but only about the general viewing pipeline.